# Unfolding Keras model summary for two joint sequential models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I had two Keras models named encoder, a decoder which I joined using the below code:-

```
   model = tf.keras.Sequential()
   model.add(encoder)
   model.add(decoder)
```

in the summary( using final_model.summary() ), I got the following output:-

[image]

Is there any way by which I can expand `sequential_16` & `sequential_17` (Check image attached), to see all the layers? Here is the code for encoder & decoder:-

```
def vgg16_encoder(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding ="same", activation = "relu", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding ="same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2, 2), name = 'block3_pool'))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2, 2), name = 'block4_pool'))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding = "same", activation = "relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2, 2), name = 'block5_pool'))
    model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
    return model
```

```
def decoder():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    dropout = 0.4 
    depth = 64 *4
    dim = 8
    model.add(Dense(dim*dim*depth, input_dim=2048))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)) 
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Reshape((dim, dim, depth))) 
    model.add(Dropout(dropout)) 
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/2), 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/4), 5, padding='same')) 
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9))
    model.add(Activation('relu')) 
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(int(depth/8), 5, padding='same')) 
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)) 
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(3, 5, padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    return model
```

```
def autoencoder(encoder , decoder):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(encoder)
    model.add(decoder)
    return model
```

```
IMG_WIDTH = 64
IMG_HEIGHT = 64
encoder = vgg16_encoder((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH,3))
decoder=decoder()
model=autoencoder(encoder,decoder)
```

Note: I'm using Tensorflow version:- 2.4.0. I'm not interested in seeing individual model(encoder, decoder) summary, but in their joint model summary.

Comment: Give a reproducible code and what's your tf version?

Comment: @M.Innat I've added that to the question. And likely it's not a version issue but the default behaviour of tf.

Comment: Please add plug-n-play code. With current given code, it gives `TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=<function encoder at 0x7fee874875f0> of type <class 'function'>`.

Comment: Ops, I had put Functional API code, check new ones, I've tested it as well. Just copy & paste all code

Answer (score 2):

There's a parameter called `expand_nested=True` from **tf 2.7** for a model summary method that will disclose inner nested loop layers ([issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15239), [pr](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15250)). But as you're using a relatively older version, **tf 2.4**, you can adopt my following workaround,

```
def summary_plus(layer, i=0):
    if hasattr(layer, 'layers'):
        if i != 0: 
            layer.summary()
        for l in layer.layers:
            i += 1
            summary_plus(l, i=i)

summary_plus(model) # OK
```

Comment: Would it not just be easier to call ```print(model.layers[0].summary())``` and
```print(model.layers[1].summary())```?

Comment: @AloneTogether,  yes, that will ez to understand code
for i in range(0,len(model.layers)):
    print(model.layers[i].summary())
But, M.Innat your code is nice informative.
Thanks, M.Innat & AlongTogether for your answer.

Comment: @AloneTogether Of course. But what if we've more sub-model inside the `autoencoder` function. To get the summary we need to go through each of them manually. So, isn't it convenient to have a function to do the job? Again, it's just a simple workaround, there can be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to set the `expanded_nested` parameter of `model.summary()` to `True`, which will expand the nested models as stated in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#summary) (Does not exist in older TF versions). It is not the prettiest output, but it does the job:

```py
print(model.summary(expand_nested=True))
```

```
Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 sequential_3 (Sequential)   (None, 2048)              14714688  
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
| conv2d_13 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)        1792      |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_14 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)        36928     |
|                                                               |
| max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 32, 32, 64)     0         |
| 2D)                                                           |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_15 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 128)       73856     |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_16 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 128)       147584    |
|                                                               |
| max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 16, 16, 128)    0         |
| 2D)                                                           |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_17 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 256)       295168    |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_18 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_19 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    |
|                                                               |
| block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 8, 8, 256)       0         |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_20 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         1180160   |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_21 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_22 (Conv2D)        (None, 8, 8, 512)         2359808   |
|                                                               |
| block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 4, 4, 512)       0         |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_23 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_24 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_25 (Conv2D)        (None, 4, 4, 512)         2359808   |
|                                                               |
| block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 2, 2, 512)       0         |
|                                                               |
| flatten (Flatten)         (None, 2048)              0         |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 sequential_4 (Sequential)   (None, 64, 64, 3)         34715075  
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
| dense_1 (Dense)           (None, 16384)             33570816  |
|                                                               |
| batch_normalization_4 (Batc  (None, 16384)          65536     |
| hNormalization)                                               |
|                                                               |
| activation_5 (Activation)  (None, 16384)            0         |
|                                                               |
| reshape_1 (Reshape)       (None, 8, 8, 256)         0         |
|                                                               |
| dropout_1 (Dropout)       (None, 8, 8, 256)         0         |
|                                                               |
| up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling  (None, 16, 16, 256)    0         |
| 2D)                                                           |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DT  (None, 16, 16, 128)    819328    |
| ranspose)                                                     |
|                                                               |
| batch_normalization_5 (Batc  (None, 16, 16, 128)    512       |
| hNormalization)                                               |
|                                                               |
| activation_6 (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 128)      0         |
|                                                               |
| up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling  (None, 32, 32, 128)    0         |
| 2D)                                                           |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DT  (None, 32, 32, 64)     204864    |
| ranspose)                                                     |
|                                                               |
| batch_normalization_6 (Batc  (None, 32, 32, 64)     256       |
| hNormalization)                                               |
|                                                               |
| activation_7 (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 64)       0         |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DT  (None, 32, 32, 32)     51232     |
| ranspose)                                                     |
|                                                               |
| batch_normalization_7 (Batc  (None, 32, 32, 32)     128       |
| hNormalization)                                               |
|                                                               |
| activation_8 (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 32)       0         |
|                                                               |
| up_sampling2d_5 (UpSampling  (None, 64, 64, 32)     0         |
| 2D)                                                           |
|                                                               |
| conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DT  (None, 64, 64, 3)      2403      |
| ranspose)                                                     |
|                                                               |
| activation_9 (Activation)  (None, 64, 64, 3)        0         |
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
=================================================================
Total params: 49,429,763
Trainable params: 49,396,547
Non-trainable params: 33,216
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

For older TF versions, just run `print(model.layers[0].summary())` and `print(model.layers[1].summary())`.